# Excel VBA , code runs one one version of office but not in other?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have the following code written on excel 2013 english and it works fine. but when i run it on excel 2007 german, it stuck on this line (if rngFrom.... 3rd line on the code) How can I solve this?

```
For j = 1 To rngFrom.Cells.Count
rngTo.Cells(j).Value = rngFrom.Cells(j)
If rngFrom.Cells(j).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> rngFrom.Cells(j).Interior.Color Then
    rngTo.Cells(j).Interior.Color = rngFrom.Cells(j).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End If
Next j
```

Comment: `Cells()` takes two parameters: rows and column. I suppose the `j` is going to be the *row* so it seems like you're missing a column. Try `...Cells(j, 1)...` to use column number 1.

Comment: @mehow, `Cells()` works with one parameter as well! In such situation it refers to item's index within collection of cells.

Comment: youre right I forgot!

Answer (score 1):

> but when i run it on excel **2007** german, it stuck on this line (if rngFrom.... 3rd line on the code) Any idea..how i can solve this?.

`Range.DisplayFormat` Property was added from xl2010+ onwards.

Please see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx) MSDN link.

Quote form that link (In case the link dies off):

[image]

**EDIT**:

I believe what you are trying to compare the conditional formatting color with the cells' interior color. If yes then you can use this code as well

```
For j = 1 To rngFrom.Cells.Count
    rngTo.Cells(j).Value = rngFrom.Cells(j)
    If rngFrom.Cells(j).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color <> _
    rngFrom.Cells(j).Interior.Color Then
        rngTo.Cells(j).Interior.Color = _
        rngFrom.Cells(j).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
    End If
Next j
```

I am assuming that there is only one condition in the conditional formatting.

Comment: any idea to use this in a older versions?..i know we cant use this syntax..but how this is done in older versions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am comparing conditional formatting color and coping it to another place ..if the color is same then i dont copy the color.

Comment: ok the problem is , i don't want to copy cells with formatting or formulas with it , i want to just copy color and its value from conditionally formatted cells.

Comment: no i think it does copy formatting ..i chked it and it give me some error at the end.